# data modelling in data warehouse

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I have a fact table which has foreign key for the various dimensions. Now i have following requirement.

There is a junk dimension which has various boolean columns. Junk dimension Table has multiple rows for different combination of the boolean values. Suppose junk dimension has 16 rows for different combination of boolean values. Boolean values in a row determines the calculations in the main fact table.

Now i want a model where client can get the calculation using any of the 16 possible set of the boolean values.

How should that junk dimension be linked to the main fact table so that calculated members can be added to the cube for each combination of the boolean values. Ultimate goal is client should be able to apply the calculation by using any value out of the 16 values.

One solution could be adding the primary key of the Junk dimension as the foreign key in the fact table. With this approach we will have the 16 rows for each row of the fact table. This is not the ideal solution as it will result in the 16 * number of the rows in the fact table. Fact table already has millions of the records.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? If you already have one row for each combination, just use the row's ID as a foreign key. 4 rows means you only have two boolean flags. If there are more, then you can't just have 4 rows

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: i have many boolean columns. i mentioned 4 rows just as an example. Fact table has millions of rows. Duplicating them for each combination of boolean values does not seems a good idea

Comment: If you are building your junk dimension as a cross join for the distinct values of flags, then at a time there could be **only one** possible record in the junk dimension linked to the fact table. So, the PK-FK approach would work just fine as it would be a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: @SouravA: 1 to 1 relationship can be achieved very easily. Is it possible somehow to be able to have one to many relationship so that for each row  of the fact table i can get the any combination of the boolean value based on the client choice. boolean values are used on calculations on measures of fact table. Client might prefer to use any calculation at run time

Comment: Then create measures for various scenarios instead of trying to modifying the fact table itself if you can.

Comment: @SouravA: which type of measures should i create and on which fact table?